# elasticsearch.exceptions.SSLError: ConnectionError hostname doesn't match

Tags: python, elasticsearch, ssl

I've been using the Elasticsearch Python API to do some basic operation on a cluster (like creating an index or listing them). Everything worked fine but I decided to activate SSL authentification on the cluster and my scripts aren't working anymore.

I have the following errors :

```
Certificate did not match expected hostname: X.X.X.X. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', 'X.X.X.X'),),), 'subjectAltName': [('DNS', 'X.X.X.X')]} GET https://X.X.X.X:9201/ [status:N/A request:0.009s] Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 386, in connect
    _match_hostname(cert, self.assert_hostname or server_hostname)   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 396, in _match_hostname
    match_hostname(cert, asserted_hostname)   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 338, in match_hostname
    % (hostname, dnsnames[0])) ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: ("hostname 'X.X.X.X' doesn't match 'X.X.X.X'",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 233, in perform_request
    method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 376, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 386, in connect
    _match_hostname(cert, self.assert_hostname or server_hostname)   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 396, in _match_hostname
    match_hostname(cert, asserted_hostname)   File "/home/esadm/env/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 338, in match_hostname
    % (hostname, dnsnames[0])) urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: ("hostname 'X.X.X.X' doesn't match 'X.X.X.X'",)
```

The thing I don't understand is that this message doesn't make any sense :

> `"hostname 'X.X.X.X' doesn't match 'X.X.X.X'"`

Because the two adresses matches, they are exactly the same !

I've followed the docs and my configuration of the instance Elasticsearch looks like this :

```
Elasticsearch([get_ip_address()],
               http_auth=('elastic', 'pass'),
               use_ssl=True,
               verify_certs=True,
               port=get_instance_port(),
               ca_certs='ca.crt',
               client_cert='pvln0047.crt',
               client_key='pvln0047.key'
               )
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The certificate data does not match and the SSL connection is rejected. You need a valid certificate and the right hostname for the connection, or deactivated `verify_certs` (which will make the connection insecure).

Comment: I believe the hostname I specified is the right hostname and we can see that because it's telling me that "hostname 'X.X.X.X' doesn't match 'X.X.X.X'" where X.X.X.X is the same address.

Comment: The problem is that when you created the certificate you put the IP address X.X.X.X in the subject alt name with a type of dNSName. It must have the type of iPAddress.

Comment: I didn't use dns name to specify the IP address, I did use the address itself (X.X.X.X where X is a number)

Comment: That error message says you did. The point is you used an IP address where a DNS name should be. You need to use the IP address where an IP address should. Feel free to add details about how the certificate was generated.

Comment: This is how I generated the certificates : 
bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert ca --pem --in /tmp/instance.yml --out /home/user/certs.zip

And this is my instance.yml : 

instances:
  - name: 'X.X.X.X'
    dns: [ 'X.X.X.X' ]

Comment: When I  put the DNS name in my instance.yml file instead of the IP address it says : 

elasticsearch.exceptions.SSLError: ConnectionError(("hostname 'X.X.X.X' doesn't match 'nameofthedns'",)) caused by: SSLError(("hostname 'X.X.X.X' doesn't match 'nameofthedns'",))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved, the issue was in the constructor :

```
Elasticsearch([get_ip_address()],
               http_auth=('elastic', 'pass'),
               use_ssl=True,
               verify_certs=True,
               port=get_instance_port(),
               ca_certs='ca.crt',
               client_cert='pvln0047.crt',
               client_key='pvln0047.key'
               )
```

Instead of mentioning the ip address I needed to mention the **DNS name**, I also changed the arguments by using context object just to follow the original docs.

```
context = create_default_context(cafile="ca.crt")
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="pvln0047.crt", keyfile="pvln0047.key")
context.verify_mode = CERT_REQUIRED
Elasticsearch(['dns_name'],
               http_auth=('elastic', 'pass'),
               scheme="https",
               port=get_instance_port(),
               ssl_context=context
               )
```

This is how I generated the certificates :

```
bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert ca --pem --in /tmp/instance.yml --out /home/user/certs.zip
```

And this is my instance.yml file :

```
instances:
  - name: 'dns_name'
    dns: [ 'dns_name' ]
```

Hope, it will help someone !